# c++ pthread_create within method

Tags: pthreads

Is there an easy way to create a new pthread each time a method is called?

I have a method activating in certain circumstances and it is the only way to commumicate with another program. I need to engage sleep and execute another method after said method is called, there is an option of another call during waiting - this is the reason i wanted to use threads.

I wanted to use standard:

```
 pthread_create(&new_thread, NULL, threadbody() );
```

Put like this

```
std::vector<phtread_t> thread(20)
...
pthread_t new_thread;
int rc;
rc = pthread_create(&new_thread, NULL, threadbody() );
threads.push_back(new_thread);
```

But i either get the errors of bad using of (void *) functions.

```
argument of type ‘void* (App::)(void*)’ does not match ‘void* (*)(void*)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is a non-static member of the class.  This is a no-no since pthread_create is only meant to work in the C realm.

To offset this, you can have

```
class X
{
public:
  static void* callback(void* p)
  {
    X* x = reinterpret_cast<X*>(p);
    x->function();
    return 0;
  }

  void function(void)
  {
     // do work here
  }
};

X obj;
pthread_create(&new_thread, &obj, &X::callback);
```

Comment: I also get a problem with attributes sent do pthread_create, how should I call it properly? (lets say i want to send INT attribute)

Comment: You could have your attribute be a public member of the class X.  Then, inside callback, you can use it as desired.  Once you are in function, any of your member objects and functions are accessible.